# Storing a 100k by 100k array in MySQL

Tags: mysql, database

I need to store a massive, fixed size square array in MySQL. The values of the array are just INTs but they need to be accessed and modified fairly quickly.

So here is what I am thinking:

- Just use 1 column for primary keys and translate the 2d arrays indexes into single dimensional indexes. 
  So if the 2d array is n by n => 2dArray[i][j] = 1dArray[n*(i-1)+j]

This translates the problem into storing a massive 1D array in the database.

- Then use another column for the values.
- Make every entry in the array a row.

However, I'm not very familiar with the internal workings of MySQL.

100k*100k makes 10 billion data points, which is more than what 32 bits can get you so I can't use INT as a primary key. And researching stackoverflow, some people have experienced performance issues with using BIGINT as primary key.

In this case where I'm only storing INTs, would the performance of MySQL drop as the number of rows increases?

Or if I were to scatter the data over multiple tables on the same server, could that improve performance? Right now, it looks like I won't have access to multiple machines, so I can't really cluster the data.

I'm completely flexible about every idea I've listed above and open to suggestions (except not using MySQL because I've kind of committed to that!)

Comment: You only have one primary key per row. So if you only have 100k rows, you can easily use an INT primary key. Can you show a sample data set? How will you be querying the data?

Comment: One row of 100k columns looks awkward. I would compromise and divide each array row in 1000 mysql rows. You end up with 100M sql rows which is doable and requires only 32bit keys.

Comment: One thing you will want to consider is what table format to use. MyISAM would have performance advantages in your scenario.

Comment: I've seen a good amount of posts debating the performance issues with having 100 columns so I just assumed having 100k columns would be impossible. @LSerni I'm confused about what you suggested. Did you mean 1000 mysql columns?

Comment: No, I mean you store each 100k 1D array not in 100k rows with one column value, or one row with 100k values, but in 1000 rows of 100 values each. Or depending on your update pattern, maybe 10000 rows of 10 values each. In total you have 1000*100k = 100M rows or 10000*100k = 1 billion rows.

Comment: It's bad advice to use MyISAM. That storage engine is being phased out, so it's almost always a wrong idea to use it.

Comment: Could you give more details about the project? What you wrote can be implemented in an infinite number of ways. For example we don't even know if a sparse matrix structure can be used or not.

Answer (score 2):

As for your concern that BIGINT or adding more rows decreases performance, of course that's true. You will have 10 billion rows, that's going to require a big table and a lot of RAM. It will take some attention to the queries you need to run against this dataset to decide on the best storage method.

I probably recommend using *two* columns for the primary key. Developers often overlook the possibility of a compound primary key.

Then you can use INT for both primary key columns if you want to.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  array_index1 INT NOT NULL,
  array_index1 INT NOT NULL,
  datum WHATEVER_TYPE NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (array_index1, array_index2)
);
```

Note that a compound index like this means that if you search on the second column without an equality condition on the first column, the search won't use the index. So you need a secondary index if you want to support that.

100,000 columns is not supported by MySQL. MySQL has [limits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html) of 4096 columns and of 65,535 bytes per row (not counting BLOB/TEXT columns).

Storing the data in multiple tables is possible, but will probably make your queries terribly awkward.

You could also look into using table [PARTITIONING](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/partitioning.html), but this is not as useful as it sounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But why would a bigger database require more memory, given that I structure my SQL queries correctly? Isn't the entire point of using a database that it doesn't require memory?

Comment: Fetching data from the buffer pool (RAM) is orders of magnitude faster than fetching from disk. You want your more frequently-requested data to be in the buffer pool. You don't need the full database to be in RAM, but the "hot" data should be. We assume in a larger database, the portion of it that is "hot" is also larger. So we benefit from more RAM.